# I want to upload an image to Imgur using Next.js API route

Tags: javascript, next.js, imgur

I am trying to create a process that uploads an image, previews it once, and then uploads it to `Imgur` if the image is OK.

---

The code is as follows.

```js
const [img, setImg] = useState([])
const previewImg = ({ target: { files } }) => {
  if (img.length > 5) return
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => {
    setImg((img) => [...img, { id: generateID(), src: result }])
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
}

const uploadImugr = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const base64 = img[0].src.toString().replace(/data:.*\/.*;base64,/, '');
  const res = await fetch('/api/upload/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: base64,
  });
  console.log(await res.json());
}

return (
  <>
    <input type="file" onChange={previewImg} />
    {img.length > 0 && img.map((item) => {
      return <img key={item.id} src={item.src} />}
    }
    <button onClick={uploadImgur}>Upload Imgur</button>
  </>
)
```

The following is the API route for next.js.
[Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#de179b6a-3eda-4406-a8d7-1fb06c17cb9c)

```js
const uploadImugrAPI = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
　formData.append('image', req.body);
  const resImgur = await fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Client-ID MY-CLIEND-ID',
    },
    body: formData,
  })
  res.status(200).json(resImgur.json());
};

export default uploadImugrAPI;
```

When the above API is executed, the following error message will be displayed.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
```

I'm new to Next.js and external APIs, so I'm not sure what keywords to search on Google for to solve this problem.
Please help me.
Thank you.

---

### Add

When I tried with `Postman`, I was able to upload images to Imugr by passing a binary file.
Therefore, I changed the code as follows to pass a binary file instead of base64 and tried it.

```js
  const [imgArray, setImgArray] = useState([])
+ const [srcArray, setSrcArray] = useState([])
  const uploadImg = ({ target: { files } }) => {
    if (imgArray.length > 5) return
+    setImgArray((imgArray) => [...imgArray, files[0]])
     const reader = new FileReader()
     reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => {
       const uploadImgSrc = result.toString()
       setSrcArray((srcArray) => [
         ...srcArray,
         { id: generateID(), src: uploadImgSrc.toString() },
       ])
     formRef.current.inputImg.value = ''
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
  }

  const uploadImugr = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
+   const formData = new FormData();
+   formData.append("image", imgArray[0])
    const res = await fetch('/api/upload/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });
    console.log(await res.json());
  }
```

The result was that the following error was displayed in the console.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
Request failed with status code 500
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.I have fixed the code.(The error message did not change.)

Comment: Is the request to the Imgur API successful? Do you get the expected response?

Comment: The request failed and we did not get the expected response, we expect to see a json in the console with the information of the uploaded image as described in the Imgur API Document.

Comment: Then there's an issue with your request. Can you successfully do the same request from Postman?

Comment: In Postman, I got the expected response by specifying an image file in the "image" field of the body! However, entering a base64 code in the "image" field of the body returned a 400 error.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days of frustration, I've patched together a solution based on several answers I stumbled upon. Convert the file to base64 client side and send that as json to the API.

```
//client.tsx
    async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!file) return;
        let base64Img = await getBase64(file);
        if (typeof base64Img == 'string') {
            base64Img = base64Img.replace(/^data:.+base64,/, '')
        }
        const result = await fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({image: base64Img}),
        })
        const response = await result.json() // response.data is an object containing the image URL

    }

    function getBase64(file: File): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer | null> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
        })
    }
```

```
//upload.ts
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const fd = new FormData(); 
    fd.append('image', req.body.image)
    fd.append('type', 'base64')
    const response = await fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Client-ID process.env.IMGUR_ID",
        },
        body: fd,
        redirect: 'follow',
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    return res.json(data)
}
```

Also I found using https://api.imgur.com/3/image instead of https://api.imgur.com/3/upload better as the errors were more helpful.